# T-SQL: date modification, only days and months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016, in one table, I want to change a date column as:

```
1936-12-15
1928-11-04
1940-09-18
1933-04-26
1942-08-17
```

To the one below, changing only months and days to 05-20, keeping only the years!

```
1936-05-20
1928-05-20
1940-05-20
1933-05-20
1942-05-20
```

I tried the following:

```
UPDATE [column]
SET [column] = DATEADD(mm, 5, [column])
```

But it added 5 months to all dates!

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Look at DATEADD help, you're are using a wrong parameter

Comment: Do you want it to be the 5/20 _after_ the original date, or the 5/20 of the same year as the date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be using SQL Server:

```
UPDATE [column]
    SET [column] = datefromparts(year(column), 5, 20);
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you can do:

```
UPDATE [column]
    SET [column] = datename(year, column) + '0520'
```

This will automatically convert the string to the correct date (although you could add an explicit `cast()`/`convert()` as well).

Answer (score 1):

Using `FORMATMESSAGE`:

```
UPDATE tab
SET col = FORMATMESSAGE('%i0520',YEAR(col));
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5df76fc885949f7e17a82d422aa873e6)**

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [Table]
  SET [column] = FORMAT([column],'yyyy-05-20')
```

Comment: More detail as to how this solves the issue and why you chose this approach would make this answer much more useful to future readers. Searches for solutions to problems are more likely to be successful when there's context around the solution itself.